# Network communication using jabber

Tags: android, http, networking, xmpp, chat

In my Android application, I am using jabber to communicate with server. I am using HTTP protocol to send the data. Is it possible to read the username and password if someone is intercepting the data? Do I need to use HTTPS or Jabber's own protection mechanisms will work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTTPS to protect your credentials. You did not say which kind of auth mechanism you are using (as some are more secure than other), but anyway, use HTTPS. Encryption on the wire is important.